# Why am I getting System.InvalidCastException when using a combobox to change serial ports? VB.NET 2019

Tags: vb.net, exception, variable-assignment, communication

I created a variable as a new serialport like so:

```vb
Public Shared panelComm As New SerialPort("COM3")
```

Now, it keeps giving me this exception when using a combobox that populates with a list of available COM ports to try and change the port number:

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort'.'`

My code to change it is this:

```vb
panelComm.Close()
panelComm = panelCOMdrp.SelectedItem
panelComm.Open()
```

`panelComm` is the port variable and `panelCOMdrp` is the dropdown combobox that has the list of ports.

**EDIT:** This is the code I use to populate the list of Serial ports available to the program:

```vb
For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
      panelCOMdrp.Items.Add(sp)
Next
```

Comment: Instead of `panelComm`, set `panelComm.PortName`.  See [SerialPort.PortName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.portname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_PortName) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If your combo stores the names of the serial port then each Item is a string not a SerialPort object instance. This is the reason of the error message. You are trying to assign a string to a variable whose type is SerialPort. The compiler doesn't automatically create a SerialPort from that string even if the string is a valid name for a SerialPort.

You need to be explicit and create a SerialPort instance from that string and thus you should write (as you do when you declare the variable)

```
' Always check if a selection is present or not
if panelCOMdrp.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    panelComm = New SerialPort(panelCOMdrp.SelectedItem.ToString())
End If
```

The @nbk's observation in the comment below is right because *SelectedItem* is defined of type *Object*. This definition together with the constructors for a *SerialPort* causes a problem. SerialPort has many overloads and one of these overloads expects an IContainer while another one expects a String. Passing just SelectedItem (an Object) force the compiler to choose the constructor that expects an IContainer and this creates the error. Just adding ToString will solve the problem and the right constructor will be choosen.

Comment: It isn't giving me the same error anymore, but now it gives me this: `BC30519 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Overloads Sub New(container As IContainer)': Argument matching parameter 'container' narrows from 'Object' to 'IContainer'.
    'Public Overloads Sub New(portName As String)': Argument matching parameter 'portName' narrows from 'Object' to 'String' 
`

Comment: I replaced the .SelectedItem with .SelectedText and it appears to have worked. Probably update answer to reflect this

Comment: Well, I would like to know how do you have filled the combobox then. SelectedText is good but if the combo is filled using strings the SelectedItem should have worked as well. Can you please add to your question the code that loads the combo with its items? So I can add the correct way to use SelectedItem

Comment: have you tried selectedItem.ToString( brcause selected item is defined as Object not string. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.7.2